# How to play animated GIF in TextView?

Tags: android, textview, animated-gif

I'm using `TextView` for displayng text with `GIF` images:

```
Html.ImageGetter imageGetter=new Html.ImageGetter imageGetter() {
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        return getDrawableFromSd(String source);
    }
}
mtTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text,imageGetter,null));
```

Some files are animated, but it doesn't animate when displaying in `TextView`. How to display it with animation?

Comment: Are you seriously trying to display a *graphic* in a View designed to display *text*?

Comment: But how to display text with animated smiles in ListView's item another way?

Comment: Maybe `WebView` is a better component for your case?

Comment: Perhaps you can try the `ObjectAnimator` or `AnimationDrawable`. But those are actually not suitable for displaying gif files.

Comment: @Gary111, WebView is slow in ListView, as I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use Glide to display gif rather than using WebView. its as simple as

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(gifImageUrl)
    .asGif()
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
    .crossFade()
    .into(imageView);
```

[image: gif support glise]

You may also like to read this post :- http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 10):

> How to play animated GIF in TextView?

You don't. Android has little support for animated GIFs, and definitely not via an `ImageSpan` in a `TextView`.

> But how to display text with animated smiles in ListView's item another way?

Most likely, you don't.

You are welcome to try an `AnimationDrawable` when you create your `ImageSpan`. Or, you are welcome to try something like a `LevelListDrawable`, where you "animate" it yourself by switching between levels on a periodic basis.